# How to get correct percentage values while using calculated items in OBIEE?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, obiee

There is an analysis on given date that has store codes as dimension and two revenue values (**Saldo 1 and Saldo 2**), a difference between them (**Difference**), and percentage (**Perc**) by using (**Saldo1 / Saldo 2) * 100** ) as measures.
[image]
While running this analysis without creating calculated items, all data is correct. But when store codes are combined as calculated items, then percentage is also showing sum of all percentage values.

Here is a result without calculated item:

[image]

Then we created a new calculated item:

[image]

And now result looks like this:

[image]

So in this case, BI getting sums of all values that correspond to Home Store including percentage values, which is logical action to do.However, if calculated item is used we should get percentage as

> sum(saldo1) / sum(saldo2) * 100

Is there any way to tell OBIEE not to sum percentages? We tried to change default aggregation rule but that didn't help.

Comment: I also experienced this, so I used Grand Total feature instead of the Calculated Items and it calculated the correct percentage formula

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the solution you are looking for:

```
cast(b-a as DOUBLE PRECISION)/nullif(c,0))*100
```

You can find more details under the link below:

https://blog.redpillanalytics.com/obiee-weird-results-when-calculating-percentages-or-ratios-73c0b09e84b7

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately this didn't work.